# Spring paging and sorting

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

If I have the following reposirory

```
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Integer> {

    List<Product> findAllByPrice(double price, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Do i have to supply a sort parameter to spring.. or will spring maintain the order somehow. Example i request page 2 without sort how will it ensure it doesn't return me page 1 results.

it might maintain an offset but how does it ensure the sql order is maintained.

So im using postgresql which doesnt guarantee the order of rows when 'ORDER BY' is not used.

If i dont happen to use it, would that mess up spring paging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to supply it each time as this is just passed to a query in the backing DB.  So the sort "goes before the paging" in essense.  In other words you are taking a page of the sorted result set. This is because another thread may have changed the DB data such that the sort and pages are different in successive calls than they would have been if only one calling client ever.

This helped me constructing correct call URLs from a JS front end:

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-pagination-in-spring